# Space complexity of a prefix tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, prefix

Given an array of urls, if stored in a prefix tree, what is the space-complexity? (Big-O, Big-Theta, Big-Omega). The length of the array is n.

Also would the Big-O change if it was optimized using a radix tree?

Comment: If the URLs are "any size", why would there be *any* bound on the space used?

Comment: URLs have limited size

Comment: Edited question! The length of the array is n. i.e. the number of urls.

Comment: O(sigma(url.length))

Answer (score 0):

It will take O(n) space... But there's a big difference between 10 bytes per URL and 100!

Using a radix tree, carefully coded, you can expect to save a significant amount of space (50%ish) over raw storage in an array, if your URLs have a lot of common prefixes.  This will be the case, for example, if they were generated by a crawler.